# Новый стиль репутации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, репутация

> [image: верхняя панель]

Мне нравится значение репутации белым цветом на белом фоне: способствует развитию скромности -

> "... чтобы не мог возгордиться человек, чтобы человек был грустен и
>   растерян."

Венедикт Ерофеев "Москва-Петушки"

Comment: А я и не заметил) Впрочем, не заметить было несложно

Comment: На английском всё ок...

Comment: @vp_arth, Только о себе думают, расисты.

Comment: У меня на iPad уже давно [вовсе нет репутации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309277/339911).

Comment: Странно, у меня всё по-старому даже после сброса кэша сочетанием Ctrl+F5. Уже починили?

Comment: @Arhad У меня тоже уже восстановилось.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема затронула все локализованные сайты SO и уже исправлена. Соответствующий баг репорт на MSE:

[New reputation color makes it very hard to read on international Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311574/339911)

Answer (score 0):

Так зрение тренируют.
Зашёл - не возгордился от мощи своей, да зрение проверил.
Сплошная польза.